# plugins error while rceating a vue project with vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

i am using vue-cli to create a new project but when i run:

```
vue create my-project
```

i get this error:

```
  Invoking generators...
 ERROR  ReferenceError: ejs:11
    9|     <h3>Installed CLI Plugins</h3>
    10|     <ul>
 >> 11| <%_ for (plugin of plugins) { _%>
    12|       <li><a href="<%- plugin.link %>" target="_blank"><%- plugin.name %></a></li>
    13| <%_ } _%>
    14|     </ul>

plugins is not defined
```

why is it so? it used to work before.

Comment: yarn global remove @vue/cli
yarn global add @vue/cli
or
npm uninstall -g @vue/cli
npm install -g @vue/cli